# How to make statement `import datetime` bind the datetime type instead of the datetime module?

Tags: python, python-import, python-module

After one too many times having accidentally typed `import datetime` when what was really needed was `from datetime import datetime`, I wondered whether it was possible to hack around and make the former do the latter.

That is, to recreate this behaviour (in a freshly opened interpreter session):

```
$ python -ic ''
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime(2016, 5, 27)
datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 27, 0, 0)
```

Came pretty close to faking a "callable module" below:

```
>>> import dt
>>> dt(2016, 5, 27)
datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 27, 0, 0)
```

Which was implemented like this:

```
# dt.py
import sys
import datetime

class CallableModule(object):
    def __init__(self, thing):
        self.thing = thing
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.thing.__call__(*args, **kwargs)

sys.modules['dt'] = CallableModule(datetime.datetime)
```

However it doesn't work if I try to use the filename `datetime.py` for the module, and I could not yet find any hack to get at the built-in datetime module when my own file was also called `datetime.py`.

How can we *temporarily unhide* a built-in or site-packages module, from within the shadowing module itself?  Is there any indirect way to get at the core `datetime` under this situation (perhaps similar to how we can still access `sys.__stdout__` even when `sys.stdout` has been redirected)?

**Disclaimer**: In no way suggesting that this is a sane idea - just interested if it's *possible*.

Comment: I was going to suggest going into the "real" `datetime.py` and adding `import sys; sys.modules['datetime'] = datetime` at the end, but then I realized that `datetime` is a C module.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here we go:

`datetime.py`:

```
import sys
import imp
import os

path = [p for p in sys.path if p != os.path.dirname(__file__)]
f, pathname, desc = imp.find_module('datetime', path)
std_datetime = imp.load_module('datetime', f, pathname, desc)
# if this^ is renamed to datetime, everything breaks!
f.close()

class CallableModule(object):

    def __init__(self, module, fn):
        self.module = module
        self.fn = fn

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.fn(*args, **kwargs)

    def __getattr__(self, item):
        try:
            return getattr(self.fn, item)
        except AttributeError:
            return getattr(self.module, item)

sys.modules['datetime'] = CallableModule(std_datetime, std_datetime.datetime)
```

`test.py` (lives next to `datetime.py`):

```
import datetime

print(datetime(1, 2, 3))
print(datetime.timedelta(days=1))
print(datetime.now())
```

Run `test.py`, output:

```
0001-02-03 00:00:00
1 day, 0:00:00
2016-05-27 23:16:30.954270
```

It also works with `from datetime import datetime, timedelta` etc.

This is especially hacky and fragile and will depend on your distribution. For example, apparently it doesn't work with IPython. You must import `datetime.py` before the standard library module.

To understand just how weird things get with this, if the variable `std_datetime` (the datetime module object) is renamed to `datetime`, then `datetime.datetime` is no longer the class, but rather `datetime is datetime.datetime is datetime.datetime.datetime ...`. If someone can explain why this happens, I'd love to hear it.

(note that the first comment below is from before I got to the final version)

Comment: I don't see what this adds compared to the code in the question, which already works this way.

Comment: Apparently you can write to  `sys.modules` from inside the module

Comment: Works on python3 on linux too.  Interestingly, doesn't work on ipython - presumably because ipython's startup imports datetime module already before you get a chance to!

Comment: @wim see what happens if you `del sys.modules['datetime']` first.

Answer (score 2):

With a small modification of the original idea, this actually works on python3:

```
# datetime.py
import sys, _datetime
sys.modules['datetime'] = _datetime.datetime
```